# Rails object delete or destroy method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, destroy

I've got

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', project, :method => :delete, :data => { :confirm => 'Are you sure?'       } %>
```

but when I click on "Destroy" in view, it shows me the project (routes me to `/project/:id`)

```
# routes.rb
resources :users

resources :projects do
  resources :issues  
end

resources :issues

resources :sessions


root :to => "users#index"

match "/auth/:provider/callback" => "sessions#create"
match "/signout" => "sessions#destroy", :as => :signout


# projects_controller.rb
def destroy
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  @project.destroy

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to projects_url }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

But "Edit" works well.
Do you know, where is the problem?

and there is an aplication.html.erb

```
#aplication.html.erb
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Project manager</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<% if current_user %>
    Welcome <%= current_user.username %>
    <%= link_to "Signout", signout_path %>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to "Sign in with twitter", "/auth/twitter" %>
<% end %>
<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

and finally aplication.js

```
#aplication.js
= require jquery
//
= require jquery_ujs
//
= require_tree .
//
= require prototype_nested_form
//
= require jquery_nested_form

= require bootstrap
```

**PS: server restart doesnt help**

Comment: Is javascript enabled in the browser? This setup relies on javascript to make a DELETE request. Otherwise you will have to set up a form with a hidden field to set the method.

Comment: Yes, javascript is enabled. When I start another app, it work well.

Comment: How about the base layout? do you have the default Rails UJS scripts in there?

Comment: if you mean aplication.html.erb, I added it into my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it. I don't know why, but when I deleted these two lines

```
#aplication.js
= require jquery
= require jquery_ujs
```

everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', project, :method => :delete, :confirm => 'Are you sure?' %>
```

**See the doc** : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

**Update**
`destroy link` has `delete method` so that url should look like `show` but `show action` have `get method` when you check `rake routes` you can see that.
both destroy and show method display the same url but method is different. for show it's a get and for destroy it's a delete method.

Comment: It doesnt help. Same problem.

Comment: No, it seems that destroy funcionality is broken somewhere.

Comment: Have you included application.js in your layout? and have you required jquery_ujs in application.js

Comment: Aplication.js added into question. And jquery_ujs is there :(